# Put Labels on every node(Three.Point) in scene Three.JS

Tags: three.js

I am new to three.js and modifying some existing code.

The existing code is rendering a graph using "THREE.BufferGeometry" + "THREE.Points"

```
var geometryPc = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
var materialPc = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({....});
this.mesh = new THREE.Points(geometryPc, materialPc);
```

I am trying to put a label text on every node which moves with the node.

I tried:

I tried creating "THREE.Sprite" for each node and then assigning it positions relative to that node.

```
let texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas);
let spriteMaterial = new THREE.SpriteMaterial({map: texture, useScreenCoordinates: false});
let sprite = new THREE.Sprite(spriteMaterial);
```

Thats seems to be working but UI becomes too heavy when number of nodes are relatively high.

I would prefer to use "BufferGeometry" to create texts as well. But could not find a way to do that.

Is there any better way to put text on the nodes?

Comment: What do you mean by "UI becomes heavy"? performance is slow? Too many things on screen?

Comment: There is a lag while scrolling, Zoom-in and zoom-out etc.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach with sprites, altough by far the most obvious, unfortunately will not be sufficient. Each sprite, if I understand correctly, creates its own mesh with its own texture, so each causes a separate draw call. This approach is not scalable.

The way I did it was to make a shader capable of rendering different parts of an image and then make an image containing letters (in a monospace font). Then, to each point in geometry (a place where a label should be rendered), I pass such a set of parameters (shader attributes) for every letter rendered:

```
    positionX: this.position.x, //position of entire label
    positionY: this.position.y,
    positionZ: this.position.z,
    colorR: this.color.r,
    colorG: this.color.g,
    colorB: this.color.b,
    colorA: this.visible ? (this.finalAlpha) : 0,
    scale: this.camera.zoom, //scale must depend on camera zoom
    spriteNumber: this.getTextPosition(lines[i][j]), //see below ;p
    offset: j + i * 32768, //this is for positioning one particular letter, 
                           //x and y merged together because I ran out of parameters
    size: this.size
```

i and j are a "x" and "y" position of a letter in a label, the shader does offsetting by itself; other parameters should be more or less obvious :)

```
ParticleLabel.prototype.getTextPosition = function(symbol){
    switch(symbol){
    case '0': return 1;
    case '1': return 2;
    case '2': return 3;
    (...)
    case 'A': return 20;
    case 'B': return 21;
    case 'C': return 22;
    (...)
```

I can't show entire code as I made it for a commercial solution, but I'll make an example on codepen or sth later on to show a working solution.

Comment: Thanks!! I am giving it a try. But could not achieve it because of my very limited(to be honest "NO") understanding of animations and three.js.

Please share some sample if you could. Thanks Though!